# Why is my program adding a new line?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a triangle example made of "[]" using a for loop. When executed the loop should print out with the given input of 2:

```
[]
[][]
```

However when I input 2 and compile it adds another line for boxes in looking like this:

```
[]
[][]
[][][]
```

Is there a ghost mechanic to this or am I missing something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NestedLoops
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Number between 2-9: ");
        int width=input.nextInt();

        String r ="";
        for(int i=1; i<=width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                r=r+"[]";
                System.out.println(r);
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: step through your code in a debugger. Watch the r variable closely.

Comment: @SkyVar Why do you need the inner loop . Eliminate it and it will solve the issue

Comment: it grows and grows... and never gets set to "" again? You inner loop is executed 1 + 2 times. Second time, r starts as [] before you add [].

Comment: you've asked a variant of this in a new question hour later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one for loop for this:

```
    for(int i=1; i<=width; i++)
    {
        r=r+"[]";
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

Comment: -1 - The OP needs to learn how to debug stuff for himself.  You are NOT helping him by spoon-feeding him the answer.  (It is obvious that this is a learning exercise ...)

Comment: Funny people. Now go to each question in stackoverflow and down vote the straight answers to the questions and tell them that they had to give only a clue or say 'search the google' that they would find the right answer themself

Comment: @jonasnas - Please reread my comment.  Please try to understand it.  Please try to understand what the OP >>really needs<< ...

Comment: Yeah you're missing everyone's point. This person obviously didn't bother to try figuring out his/her own question. The stackexchange sites are very explicit in the FAQs about doing people's homework for them and this seemed entirely like that. Oh well to each their own.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the comments there are lots of hints about what you've done wrong.

But what you really need is advice on how to do your own trouble shooting:

- Joel suggests that you should use a debugger.  If you haven't been taught about this, you need to find a tutorial ... relevant to the IDE you are using.
- ruakh suggests adding trace prints to your code to print out the values of variables at key places.  This way works too, especially in cases where you can't attach a debugger to your program
- I suggest that you "hand execute" the program.  Get a piece of paper and pencil, write down the names of the variables and a "slot" for the values.  Now pretend you are executing the statements *exactly as they are written*, writing / changing the values of the variables on your piece of paper.

And of course, you need to use your brain to interpret what the above will tell you, build an understanding of what is actually going on, and a plan for fixing it.

Troubleshooting / debugging is something you learn to do with practice; i.e. by doing it *yourself*.  And you'll need to learn this if you are ever to become a productive programmer.

The other *good thing* about doing your own trouble-shooting is that the practice helps your develop your skills in reading and understanding code, and ultimately your skills in writing it.  And THAT ... my friend ... is the point of your homework!